# Can I obtain the Lambda Alias in my .NET Core Minimal API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In AWS API Gateway I have 3 stages: Prod, Stage and Dev
In my AWS Lambda I have 3 Aliases: PROD, STAGE, DEV

My API in API Gateway the resource points to: `my-lambda-name:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` and then I map a domain to each stage.

Below is my Lambda .NET Core Minimal API `Program.cs` code.

Is there anyway to get the Stage Variable in the `Program.cs` so that I can use that to pull the correct configuration from Parameter Store? I do not believe I can use the Lambda Environment Variables because they're the same among all Aliases.

`my-lambda-name:DEV` or `my-lambda-name:STAGE` or `my-lambda-name:PROD`

```
global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);

// Pull in Configuration
builder.Configuration.AddSystemsManager($"/AppName/{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}");

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```